# Spring optional @PathVariable?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Is it possible to somehow get a hold of a `@PathVariable` in a **[`@ControllerAdvice`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html)** given that the PathVariable is only present in *some* requests?

If this was in a Controller, I could write 2 different Controllers. But a `ControllerAdvice` always applies to *all* requests. I can't have a ControllerAdvice apply to only Controllers where the PathVariable is defined.

Comment: ´@PathVariable´ is not supported indeed in @ExceptionHandler methods.

Comment: You can have as much @ControllerAdvices as you want. But I'm wondering why you need `@PathVariable` there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can inject the Map of path variables and check for the existence of a key.

```
public void advise(@PathVariable Map<String, String> pathVariables) {
    if (pathVariables.containsKey("something")) {
        String something = pathVariables.get("something");
        // do something

    } else {
        // do something else
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this answer is ok, but it took me a while to found out that you need to add the @ModelAttribute annotation before the function. Also is good to know that you can inject any variable that you use in the controller @RequestMapping side. So for example the whole class will look like

```
@ControllerAdvice(basePackages = {"test.web.controller"}) 
public class SomeAdvicer {
    @ModelAttribute
    public void advise(@PathVariable Map<String, String> pathVariables, SomeOtherClass ctx) {
        if (pathVariables.containsKey("something")) {
            if (!pathVariables.get("something").equals(ctx.getSomething())){
                throw new Exception("failed");
           }
        } 
   }
}
```

When your controller looks like

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, value = "/{something}")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<test> updateDemo(
        @PathVariable(value = "invoicerId") 
        @RequestBody RequestMessage requestBodyMessage,
        SomeOtherClass ctx) throws RestException {  ....  }
```